# Matplotlib Legend and colormaps from panda dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, legend, colormap

I am trying to plot some graphs with Python. Specifically I am working with dataframes. I would like to know how to do the next couple of things:

1. Adapt the legend of the plots using the correspondant column name. I have checked somewhere something related with a dictioinary...However I am going to work with more columns than 4 (as in the code below as an example).
2. Adapt colormaps from matplotlib for different columns.For example, if the name of the columns is 'AA' and 'CC' then use one of the colormaps and if contains 'BB' or 'DD' use another colormaps.

I have enclosed the code below that I am using as a test.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab as plt

def Plots():
    labels_df1 = list(df1.columns.values)
    labels_df2 = list(df2.columns.values)
    labels_df3 = list(df3.columns.values)
    labels_df4 = list(df4.columns.values)

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

    axs[0, 0].plot(df1, df1, label=labels_df1)
    axs[0, 0].set_xlabel('X axis')
    axs[0, 0].set_ylabel('Y axis')
    axs[0, 0].grid(True, which='both')
    axs[0, 0].legend(loc='best', fontsize=8)

    axs[0, 1].plot(df1, df2, label=labels_df2)
    axs[0, 1].set_xlabel('X axis')
    axs[0, 1].set_ylabel('Y axis')
    axs[0, 1].grid(True, which='both')
    axs[0, 1].legend(loc='best', fontsize=8)

    axs[1, 0].plot(df1, df3, label=labels_df3)
    axs[1, 0].set_xlabel('X axis')
    axs[1, 0].set_ylabel('Y axis')
    axs[1, 0].grid(True, which='both')
    axs[1, 0].legend(loc='best', fontsize=8)

    axs[1, 1].plot(df1,  df4, label=labels_df4)
    axs[1, 1].set_xlabel('X axis')
    axs[1, 1].set_ylabel('Y axis')
    axs[1, 1].grid(True, which='both')
    axs[1, 1].legend(loc='best', fontsize=8)

    plt.show()


df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['AA','BB','CC','DD'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['AA','BB','CC','DD'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['AA','BB','CC','DD'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns=['AA','BB','CC','DD'])

Plots()
```

[image]
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: -The first point can be easily solved using `plt.legend(df1.columns.values)`.
Still working on the 2nd point of the post